# jquery remove class

Tags: jquery

i got a class,

```
div.domtab div{
        clear:both;
        width:auto;
        background:#eee;
        color:#000;
        padding:1em 1.5em;
    }
```

and i cannot change it, and i not able to remove it
i tried

```
$('#tag1').removeClass();
$('#tag1').removeClass('.domtab');
$('#tag1').removeClass('div.domtab');
$('#tag1').removeClass('div.domtab div');
```

but it still not working.
`clear:both` cause all my div not float left.....

Comment: What does your markup look like? Does `#tag1` have this class, or one of its parents does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your markup is like:

```
<div class="domtab">
  ...
  <div id="tag1"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

You can remove the class by

`$('#tag1').closest('.domtab').removeClass('domtab');`

Comment: thx its works, is it possible to just remove only clear:both, in that class.

Comment: You can write in your css: `.domtab #tag1 { clear: none; }` or jquery: `$('#tag1').css('clear', 'none');`

Answer (score 3):

try `$('#tag1').removeClass('domtab');`

Comment: @Leon please post your HTML so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You just missed out the line that is actually correct.

```
$('#tag1').removeClass('domtab');
```

The code above should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the above answers are correct, is because this method specifies "Class" in it's name, implying that it is ASSUMED you are giving it a valid class name. Being as "." implies a class, this becomes a redundancy.

Thus, when using "removeClass" a "." should not be used.