# Remove one element with a class

Tags: jquery

I have the class `.note`, and I want to press to press an "X" in the class, and it will delete that one `.note`.  But instead of deleting that one `.note`, it deletes all of them!  Here's the code:

```
$('#remove').click(function () {
    $('.note').remove();
});
```

P.S.  `#remove` is the "X"

Comment: Without seeing relevant HTML markup, how could we help?! Maybe: `$(this).closest('.note').remove();`  But you should improve your question for sure...  Now because IDs must be unique on document context, not sure it is what you are expecting

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery remove class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712772/jquery-remove-class)

Comment: @JessicaPartridge That's not relevant dupe. OP doesn't want to remove class but element with specific class

Comment: of course it does deletes all `.note`, cause that is what you select. show more markup to be more specific on your selector..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only remove the note with the button inside it then you select the parent of the button. Also, never use ID's when there is going to be more than ONE of the same thing. In this case: the remove button. Otherwise, only the FIRST one will work!

use a class instead.

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

See [Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/b57dkz4w/)

Also, for the sake of being "Future Proof" this would be a better solution:

```
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.note').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to delete

```
$('#remove').click(function () {
   $('#remove').find('.note').removeClass('note');
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This will simply remove the `note` class from all notes. It does nothing about removing the single note.