# How to remove ui-draggable class from the Div element?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove `ui-draggable` class from the `DIV` element. I am not sure how this 'ui-draggable' is added to my class.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712772/jquery-remove-class)

Comment: We are not sure either if you do not show us your code.

Comment: do you wish to remove class or disable dragging?

Comment: Having my own class for swapping div elements in a GridView. It is working fine at the first time. But after moving into another view, it stops working

Answer (score 1):

The `.ui-draggable` class is being added by jQuery UI, because you're using its [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) widget or something that depends on it.   Removing the classname manually presumably isn't working because the jQuery widget is putting it back in place.

You probably shouldn't be trying to remove this class; instead override any undesirable styling by putting rules on a different classname attached to the same element.

(If what you're really trying to do is to disable dragging for a specific element, use `$('div.foo').draggable( "disable" );` instead of removing classnames.)

Comment: Solved the issue... :). Actually my Markup was corrupted. Thanks all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div .ui-draggable').removeClass('ui-draggable');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just try using this**

```
$("div").removeClass("ui-draggable");
```

**or give your div tag an id and try this**

```
$("#divid").removeClass("ui-draggable");
```

Comment: tried.But not removing. Please see the inspect element

Comment: <div class="eachdate eachweek ui-draggable" style="position: relative;"><div id="room_0_186" class="available swap ui-draggable" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative;" draggable="false" onmousedown="javascript:selectFromDate('8/25/2017');" onmouseup="javascript:selectToDate(186,'8/26/2017',26,-1);" data-roomid="26" data-date="8/25/2017"></div></div>

Comment: call the piece of code on page load with a divid for the div you have mentioned.

Comment: For all the other classes removeClass is working. But for ui-draggable only it is not working. Can you please provide some insight why ui-draggable is added to my DiV element automatically?

Comment: Try this link it might help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324044/how-do-i-disable-a-jquery-ui-draggable

Comment: already tried. Not sure why ui-draggable class is not removing